# How to insert a XML text() value as the value for another XML element

Tags: xquery

I'm trying to insert a new XML element in my XML data type, but this new XML element must contain the value of another XML element. For example, given the following XML:

```
<Config>
    <SomeOtherNode>
        <ValueToUse>123</ValueToUse>
    </SomeOtherNode>
</Config>
```

should render the following:

```
<Config>
    <Node1>123</Node1>
    <SomeOtherNode>
        <ValueToUse>123</ValueToUse>
    </SomeOtherNode>
</Config>
```

I've attempted the following with no luck (it inserts the XQuery as the actual value):

```
update Table
set Column.modify('insert <Node1>//SomeOtherNode/ValueToUse/text()</Node1> as first into /Config')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XQuery uses curly braces to denote enclosed expressions, distinguishing the content expression from literal text. To fix your query, surround the enclosed expression with curly braces:

`<Node1>{ //SomeOtherNode/ValueToUse/text() }</Node1>`

(The whitespace inside the curly braces is just for visual clarity and isn't needed.)

The purpose of curly braces is defined in the spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-31/#doc-xquery31-EnclosedExpr:

> Definition: An **enclosed expression** is an instance of the **EnclosedExpr** production, which allows an optional expression within **curly braces**.

```
EnclosedExpr       ::=      "{" Expr? "}"
```

> Definition: In an enclosed expression, the optional expression enclosed in curly braces is called the **content expression**.

Comment: Dude, you are a legend

Comment: Happy to help, Rudolf!